# Rails save serialized object fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, serialization, yaml

See the following output:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > player = Player.randomize_for_market
 => #<Player id: nil, name: "Gale Bridges", age: 19, energy: 100, attack: 6, defense: 4, stamina: 5, goal_keeping: 3, power: 4, accuracy: 5, speed: 5, short_pass: 5, ball_controll: 4, long_pass: 6, regain_ball: 5, contract_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
1.9.3p194 :002 > player.save!
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   SQL (20.5ms)  INSERT INTO "players" ("accuracy", "age", "attack", "ball_controll", "contract_id", "created_at", "defense", "energy", "goal_keeping", "long_pass", "name", "power", "regain_ball", "short_pass", "speed", "stamina", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17) RETURNING "id"  [["accuracy", 5], ["age", 19], ["attack", 6], ["ball_controll", 4], ["contract_id", nil], ["created_at", Fri, 29 Jun 2012 04:02:34 UTC +00:00], ["defense", 4], ["energy", 100], ["goal_keeping", 3], ["long_pass", 6], ["name", "Gale Bridges"], ["power", 4], ["regain_ball", 5], ["short_pass", 5], ["speed", 5], ["stamina", 5], ["updated_at", Fri, 29 Jun 2012 04:02:34 UTC +00:00]]
   (16.6ms)  COMMIT
 => true 
1.9.3p194 :003 > YAML::load(YAML::dump(Player.randomize_for_market)).save!
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
 => true
```

Why this happens and how can I avoid it?

There is no ((before|after)+(save|create|commit)) on the model. I'm using rails 3.2.

```
                                   Table "public.players"
   Column     |            Type             |                      Modifiers                       
--------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------
id            | integer                     | not null default nextval('players_id_seq'::regclass)
name          | character varying(255)      | not null
age           | integer                     | not null
energy        | integer                     | not null
attack        | integer                     | not null
defense       | integer                     | not null
stamina       | integer                     | not null
goal_keeping  | integer                     | not null
power         | integer                     | not null
accuracy      | integer                     | not null
speed         | integer                     | not null
short_pass    | integer                     | not null
ball_controll | integer                     | not null
long_pass     | integer                     | not null
regain_ball   | integer                     | not null
contract_id   | integer                     | 
created_at    | timestamp without time zone | not null
updated_at    | timestamp without time zone | not null

Indexes:
   "players_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Edit: Answering "Why do you expect YAML::load(YAML::dump(Player.randomize_for_market)).save! to do anything?"

Because it serializes a object and recovers it?
example:

```
1.9.3p194 :006 > p = Player.randomize_for_market
 => #<Player id: nil, name: "Vincenzo Allen", age: 23, energy: 100, attack: 2, defense: 8, stamina: 6, goal_keeping: 3, power: 5, accuracy: 6, speed: 5, short_pass: 6, ball_controll: 5, long_pass: 6, regain_ball: 5, contract_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
1.9.3p194 :007 > p
 => #<Player id: nil, name: "Vincenzo Allen", age: 23, energy: 100, attack: 2, defense: 8, stamina: 6, goal_keeping: 3, power: 5, accuracy: 6, speed: 5, short_pass: 6, ball_controll: 5, long_pass: 6, regain_ball: 5, contract_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
1.9.3p194 :008 > YAML::load(YAML::dump(p))
 => #<Player id: nil, name: "Vincenzo Allen", age: 23, energy: 100, attack: 2, defense: 8, stamina: 6, goal_keeping: 3, power: 5, accuracy: 6, speed: 5, short_pass: 6, ball_controll: 5, long_pass: 6, regain_ball: 5, contract_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Note that the return of p is the same of the return from YAML::load

Comment: Why do you expect `YAML::load(YAML::dump(Player.randomize_for_market)).save!` to do anything?

Comment: Because it is supposed to serialize and recover the object? Please check my edit with a answer for you

Comment: But why would `save!` do anything to an object that hasn't actually changed? Your `.save!` call is succeeding based on the return value, lack of an exception, and the SQL `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`; but if nothing has changed then why would you expect `save` to be something other than a no-op?

Comment: Since the object has null ID before the save, isn't supposed to it got a new one and be saved on the database? Note on the first example I gave how the first generated player is save, and the second is not.

Comment: But there is a fair bit of state that won't be in the YAML'd object so the internal state before dump/load won't be the same as it is after. For example, grab one of your model instances (`m`) in the console, change an attribute (`a`), do your `m2 = YAML::load(YAML::dump(m))`, and then see what `m2.a_changed?` has to say. Perhaps you should explain what you're actually trying to accomplish with this round trip through YAML.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may help to answer your question:

```
:001 > article = Article.new
#<Article:0x102d16b10> { ... }
:002 > article.persisted?
false
:003 > dumped = YAML::dump(article)
"--- !ruby/object:Article ... "
:004 > loaded = YAML::load(dumped)
#<Article:0x102cf5500> { ... }
:005 > loaded.persisted?
true
```

Looking into the Rails source code for [`ActiveRecord::Base#persisted?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-persisted-3F):

```
def persisted?
  !(new_record? || destroyed?)
end
```

And for [`ActiveRecord::Base#new_record?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-new_record-3F):

```
def new_record?
  @new_record
end
```

The `@new_record` instance variable is not saved when you dump the object to Yaml, and therefore it's `nil` when you load the object from Yaml. So ActiveRecord thinks it's already been persisted to the database and doesn't attempt to save it.

Comment: Yeah, the YAML only contains the data that goes in the table, the important things that tell ActiveRecord what needs to be done with that data don't survive the round trip through YAML. +1 for tracking down a few more missing pieces.

Answer (score 2):

Brandan's answer is very relevant, the object de-serialized from YAML thinks it's already been persisted. Assuming `@loaded_obj` is the object you loaded from YAML (the object you want to save), try `@loaded_obj.dup.save`

Comment: In Rails 4, `loaded_obj.persisted?=false`, which is correct but apparently the code doesn't "realize" that any values have changed so it doesn't save any values.  Using **dup()** solves the problem.